# sql reporting server virtual directory

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have sql reporting services installed in my system.
I can access it through the url http://localhost/Reports_SQLEXPRESS/
But the strange thing is I am not able to view this virtual directory in my IIS management console. I need to set the permissions for this virtual directory, but it cannot be found. 
What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

i assume that you are using reporting service 2008 look at this two links
http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/33694
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337491.aspx

Comment: Report manager URL is given as http://localhost/Reports_SQLEXPRESS in reporting service configuration manager. But when I use that in the browser, it asks for login, and when provided admin credentials, it gets redirected to http://localhost/Reports_SQLEXPRESS/Pages/Folder.aspx. There are no property tabs, just the report server page header.

Comment: Hi, when you are logged as admin look at the top right of the site there must be Site Settings from there you can create new users roles and set permissions

Comment: No, the only links on the page are "home" and "help". I tried different admin account and even tried using "open as administrator" and then logging in with admin account.

Comment: Try adding the user you are logging as in the administrator group in the computer where the service is installed

Comment: the user is in administrator group. Morevoer I tried other accounts in the administrator group. But, the issue remains

Comment: http://odetocode.com/articles/215.aspx
this is one of the link that i used when setting my report server.I don't know what more to say in my case when adding the user to administrators group this page was visible. I have no idea wham may be the problem in your case

Answer (score 0):

Reconfigure your report server with Reporting Service Configuration Manager.